# How to do a logical "AND" with "contains" in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, contains, logical-operators

I am using `contains` to search inside my class call `.searchterms`, looks something like this:

```
$(list)
    .find(".searchterms:contains(RM),.searchterms:contains(FINAL)")
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .slideDown(0);
```

but that is logical `OR` and what I want is the objects that have `RM` AND `FINAL`

Answer (score 1):

You do it just like you have with `.searchterms` and `:contains`: By joining them:

```
$(list).find(".searchterms:contains(RM):contains(FINAL)").parent().parent().slideDown(0);
// ------------------------------------^
```